# Mean survival time of a Weibull distribution

Tags: survival, weibull-distribution

I'm trying to calculate the mean survival time of a Weibull distribution, and am getting what feels like an errant estimate of the mean--and each source I look up for how to calculate the mean gives a slightly different formulation.

Going from Klein and Moeschberger, the mean is:

$$\frac{\Gamma(1+1/\alpha)}{\lambda^{1/\alpha}}$$

As I understand it, $\alpha$ is the shape parameter, and $\lambda$ is $\exp(\beta_0...\beta_ k)$ for a model with $k$ terms. Is this correct?

Thus, for a model with two $\beta$ terms, $\beta_0 = 2.18$ and $\beta_1 = 0.66$ along with an $\alpha$ of 0.88, is the mean survival time, as evaluated by R for a non-integer Gamma function as follows:

```
b0 <- 2.18
b1 <- 0.66
alpha <- 0.88

mean <- (gamma(1+(1/alpha)))/(exp(2.18+0.66)**(1/alpha))
```

Correct? That produces a mean of 0.0423, which seems...small, even for such a skewed distribution.

Comment: I'll try to write up a proper answer in a bit, but one must be *very* careful and explicit about the parametrization. In fact, $R$ uses at least two which adds to the confusion: One for the `pgamma` etc. class of functions and a different one for `survreg` etc. A good sanity check is to reduce to the exponential case by appropriate setting of the parameters and see if the answer you get is consistent.

Comment: Further double-checking against the Rayleigh case may also help.

Comment: Checking against a Exponential E(x) of 1/lambda = 1/(exp(2.18+0.66)) yields a similar estimate of 0.058.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

According to the mean you give, you use the following parametrisation for the Weibull distribution:
$$
\textrm{if }X\sim \textrm{Weibull}(\lambda, \alpha) \textrm{ then } f_X(x) = \lambda \alpha x^{\alpha - 1} \exp(-\lambda x^\alpha),
$$
with $\lambda > 0$ a scale parameter, and $\alpha > 0$ a shape parameter.

[dweibull()](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/stats/html/Weibull.html) from R, as well as [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weibull_distribution), use another parametrisation. The conversion is as follows:
$$
\textrm{shape} = \alpha \quad \textrm{and} \quad \textrm{scale} = \left(\frac{1}{\lambda} \right)^{\tfrac{1}{\alpha}},
$$
where $\textrm{shape}$ and $\textrm{scale}$ are those given in dweibull() and wikipeida.

---

Let $\mathbf{x}'\mathbf{\beta} = x_1\beta_1 + x_2\beta_2 + \dotsb$ be the linear predictor.

Assuming a proportional hazards structure and a $\textrm{Weibull}(\lambda, \alpha)$ distribution at baseline, the hazard rate is written
\begin{align*}
h(t) & = h_0(t) \exp(\mathbf{x}'\mathbf{\beta}) \\
     & = \lambda \alpha t^{\alpha - 1} \exp(\mathbf{x}'\mathbf{\beta}).
\end{align*}
The corresponding pdf is
$$
f(t) = \lambda \alpha t^{\alpha - 1} \exp(\mathbf{x}'\mathbf{\beta}) \exp \left( - \lambda t^\alpha \exp(\mathbf{x}'\mathbf{\beta}) \right).
$$
That is, $T$ has a Weibull distribution with the same shape $\alpha$ but the scale parameter is changed from $\lambda$ to $\lambda \exp(\mathbf{x}'\mathbf{\beta})$:
$$
T \sim \textrm{Weibull}(\lambda \exp(\mathbf{x}'\mathbf{\beta}), \alpha)
$$
and we have
$$
E[T] = \frac{\Gamma(1 + \tfrac{1}{\alpha})}{\left(\lambda\exp(\mathbf{x}'\mathbf{\beta})\right)^{\tfrac{1}{\alpha}}}.
$$

---

An example without covariate:

```
> #------ scale and shape parameters in your parametrisation ------
> lambda <- 3
> alpha <- 0.88
> #----------------------------------------------------------------
> 
> #------ conversion ------
> shape <- alpha
> scale <- (1 / lambda)^(1 / alpha)
> #------------------------ 
>  
> #------ some data ------
> T <- rweibull(n=10000, shape=shape, scale=scale)
> #-----------------------
>  
> #------ theoretical and empirical means ------
> gamma(1 + 1 / alpha) / (lambda^(1 / alpha))
[1] 0.305765
> mean(T)
[1] 0.3026293
> #---------------------------------------------
```

[image]

Comment: Notation has always been somewhere I'm shaky. (x'beta) is the vector of beta coefficients, yes? If so, then what's lambda?

Comment: I have edited to make it clear

Comment: I think I follow now, thank you again for the edits. In your example, lambda = 1, and the models I'm basing off this in SAS report only a single parameter in addition to the beta coefficients. That seems to suggest they too are assuming lambda = 1, and it also appears to be the default in R. Is there a reason for this? Also given your example, it appears my calculation of the mean above is correct? I confess to being a little shell-shocked by the difference between the mean and median for a Weibull with those parameters.

Comment: I have changed the example because there is no particular reason for lambda = 1. Regarding your calculation, I think you missed $\lambda$ in the scale parameter which should be $\lambda \exp(\mathbf{x}'\mathbf{\beta})$. That is, $\lambda$ from the baseline distribution (no covariate) is changed to $\lambda \exp(\mathbf{x}'\mathbf{\beta})$ when covariates are added.

Comment: Hrm. I think I see what you're saying - in the calculation I have above, I'm missing λ and only have exp(x′β)? I suppose the question is then if I only have what appear to be estimates of β0, β1 and a single other parameter that I believe is alpha, is it possible to calculate λ?

Comment: (i) Maybe $\lambda$ is given a default value of $1$ as you claimed in a previous comment (?). 
(ii) If you are also given the mean (or the median, or sthg similar), then you can retrieve $\lambda$.
(iii) If neither (i) nor (ii) holds, then I do not think it is possible to get $\lambda$.

Comment: ...and just found a specification for λ in the code, it ends up not getting reported but does get used. Accepting your answer.